# Question in finding final position in circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

im having difficulty solving this problem right now, I tried couple of times but i couldnt figure it out, can you please help and explain?

thank you

[image: the porlbem]

Answer (score 1):

For these questions, you'll want to use the formula for the arc length of a circle given by

$$L=\theta r$$

You want to find $L$ where $\theta$ is the angle measured from the starting position to the end position in *radians* (not degrees) and $r$ is the distance from the center of the circle (in this case, 27 cm).

You already know $r$, so each question is essentially asking you to find a new $\theta$.

Imagine the center of the fan is at the origin of the Cartesian plane.They give you the horizontal distance from the y-axis (i.e., vertical diameter), so you'll need to set up right triangles and use your trig functions to solve for the angle formed.

For part a), we know that the the right triangle formed has a side length 6 and hypotenuse 27, so $\arcsin(6/27) \approx .224$ radians. Add that to the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians formed by the bug traveling through the first quadrant and we get $\theta \approx 1.794$ radians.

\begin{align}
L &\approx 27 \cdot 1.794
\\
& \approx 48.438 \, \textrm{cm}
\end{align}

Repeat for the rest of the parts setting up a different triangle each time.

Comment: I tried the same method for the other 2 but I still get the wrong answer, why is that?

Comment: Did you get the correct answer for the first one?

Comment: I did get the first one correct

Comment: Post your work, and we'll take a look at it together. It probably has to do with your triangles.

Comment: Also, make sure you're in radians, not degrees.